# SQLite database locked after showing a DataGrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlite

I have a Sub to show data on a DataGridView but after this sub I can't add files because I get a database is locked message.

I tryed using 
SQLiteConnection.ClearAllPools()

and
GC.Collect()

But is the same. Also I tryed to make the Using block as small as possible.

**Any clue why the database is locked after this code?**

```vb
Private Sub LoadDataGridView1()

    Dim connLoadDataGrid = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=myDataBase.sqlite;Version=3")

    Try
        Using (connLoadDataGrid)

            connLoadDataGrid.Open()

            Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM users"

            Dim cmdDataGrid As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sql, connLoadDataGrid)

            'Load data on a Table
            Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter
            da.SelectCommand = cmdDataGrid
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

            'Change the name of the columns
            With DataGridView1
                .RowHeadersVisible = False
                .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "ID"
                .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Name"
                .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Type"
                .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Notes"
            End With

            'Autoadjust the columns
            DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader)

            Dim readerDataGrid As SQLiteDataReader = cmdDataGrid.ExecuteReader()

       End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
```

End Sub

Comment: You are leaving a lot of DB Provider objects behind.Whats is that DataReader for in the last line?

Comment: @Plutonix Right !! It was my mistake. I removed the line and now is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, your code leaves several other things undisposed: the `DbCommand`, `DataAdapter` and most importantly, an odd `DataReader` is created at the end which remains open and alive.  Anything which implements the `Dispose` method ought to be created and used in a `Using` block to be sure it is disposed and resources released.

This is especially important with SQLite since the DB is just a file.

---

For basic add/change/delete apps your can create a `DataAdapter` which will live for the life of your app/form and be able to perform *all the DB operations for you*:

```vb
' form/class level objects
Private daLite As SQLiteDataAdapter
Private dtLite As DataTable
```

Initializing the DB provider objects:

```vb
' spell out your SQL
Dim SQL = "SELECT Id, Name, Fish, Bird, Color, Price FROM Sample"

' persistent datatadapter
daLite = New SQLiteDataAdapter(SQL, LiteConnStr)
dtLite = New DataTable

' teach the DA how to do everything
Dim cb As New SQLiteCommandBuilder(daLite)
daLite.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand
daLite.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand
daLite.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand

' load schema, table
daLite.FillSchema(dtLite, SchemaType.Source)
daLite.Fill(dtLite)

dgv1.DataSource = dtLite
```

Passing the connection string rather than a connection object, lets the `DataAdapter` create its own connection which it will open and close as needed.  At the end, it knows how to add, insert and delete from the database because it "holds onto" those command objects.  You may not need any other SQL in the app.

Note that each row in the `DataTable` has a `RowState` which indicates if it is  added, deleted or changed so you can accumulate several changes before updating the database:

```vb
' dataadapter will open its connection, then close 
Dim rows = daLite.Update(dtLite)
```

All the new rows are added, changed ones are updated, deleted ones are deleted. `rows` will be the total number of them.

Another benefit is that you will be able to "refresh" the rows.  If changes are being made outside the app (such as by you in a UI DB browser).  Performing `daLite.Fill(dtLite)` again later, picks up just those changes.

**Notes**

- In this case you would *not* dispose of the DBCommand, DBConnection etc in the procedure (or anywhere) because the plan is to use it over and over.
- You should spell out your SQL to control the order of the DGV column display.

  - For the above to work, the Primary Key needs to be part of the SQL.
- Incidentally, changing the DGV `HeaderText` doesnt change the column name, just the displayed text.
- When using something like this for bulk imports, a `Transaction` will speed it up.

This only works on simple one table queries as yours appears to be.

Comment: Thanks again. I need to read, study and learn youre complete answer. I hope it serve for anothers visitors!

Comment: Basically the dataadapter "holds onto" the INSERT and DELETE etc SQL so all you have to do it is `myDA.Update(myDT)` for anything.